# Spring boot hibernate 5 integration error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to integrate spring Boot with Hibernate 5 using Java configs.
It has been some time since I have used Hibernate.
I am getting the below mentioned exception. Can someone please suggest how to resolve this ?

Following is my java config file followed by the exception stack trace.

```
package com.example;

import com.example.dao.CustomerDao;
import com.example.model.Customer;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringHibernateDemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringHibernateDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        //SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        // dataSource.setDriverClass((Class<? extends Driver>)Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"));
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customerDB");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("welcome");
        return  dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean  sessionFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","create");
       // properties.put("hibernate.connection.provider_class","org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider");
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.example.model");
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
        /*SessionFactory sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource()).
                addAnnotatedClass(Customer.class).setProperties(properties).buildSessionFactory();*/
        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "hibernateTemplate")
    public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() throws ClassNotFoundException {

        return new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomerDao customerDao() {
        return  new CustomerDao();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setFistName("amar");
        customer.setLastName("dev");
        customer.setEmail("amar@gmail.com");
        customerDao().saveCustomer(customer);
    }
}
```

The exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:809) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:790) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:777) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SpringHibernateDemoApplication.main(SpringHibernateDemoApplication.java:23) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@10753c9] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@ba5d30] bound to thread [main]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:190) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:127) ~[spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:454) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.0.Final.jar:5.2.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:326) ~[spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:309) ~[spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:616) ~[spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.dao.CustomerDao.saveCustomer(CustomerDao.java:11) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.dao.CustomerDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fb200467.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.dao.CustomerDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22cf791b.saveCustomer(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.SpringHibernateDemoApplication.run(SpringHibernateDemoApplication.java:71) [main/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:806) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Don't use plain hibernate, use JPA instead with hibernate as the provider. Remove the datasource, remove the session factory and hibernate template and rewrite your dao using an `EntityManager`. Also don't call `customerDao()` but inject the bean instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum But why should it be this way ? What is wrong in the current way ?

Comment: I understand not calling customerDao() , but completely changing it to EntityManager is puzzling me!!!

Comment: The current way binds your code to Hibernate explicitly. The JPA is now standard accepted for ORM for database interaction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is you aren't defining a `HibernateTransactionManager` next to that Spring Boot detects hibernate and JPA and automatically configures it. Both technologies try to start a transaction and that fails. Instead work with the framework, Spring Boot already auto configures a `DataSource` and `EntityManagerFactory` (the JPA variant of a `SessionFactory`) for you.

### Missing `HibernateTransactionManager`

If you really want to use plain Hibernate add a transaction manager.

```
@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sf) {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sf);
}
```

### Use Spring Boot to configure DataSource

I would however urge you to use the framework.
Create a file called `application.properties` in `src/main/resources` and put the following properties in it.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customerDB
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=welcome
```

Now you can remove the `DataSource` and you can rewrite your `sessionFactory` method to take a `DataSource` as method argument.

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean  sessionFactory(DataSource ds) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    ... // Other settings here
    return localSessionFactoryBean;
}
```

### Use JPA instead of plain Hibernate

However instead of doing this I suggest removing everything and add the following to your configuration (the `application.properties`).

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect
```

Now in your `SpringHibernateDemoApplication` you can remove everything but your `CustomerDao` (unless that is annotated with `@Repository` you could remove that as well). Spring Boot already detects and enables transactions so you can also remove the `@EnableTransactionManagement`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringHibernateDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringHibernateDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomerDao customerDao() {
        return  new CustomerDao();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner runner(CustomerDao dao) {
        return new CommandLineRunner() {
            @Override
            public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
                Customer customer = new Customer();
                customer.setFistName("amar");
                customer.setLastName("dev");
                customer.setEmail("amar@gmail.com");
                dao.saveCustomer(customer);
            }            
        };
    }
}
```

The only thing for you to do is to replace the use of `HibernateTemplate` (which isn't recommended in the first place!) with the use of an `EntityManager`. See the [JPA Section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight) of the reference guide.

```
@Repository
public class CustomerDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
        em.persist(customer);
    }
}
```

### Use Spring Data JPA

However if you want to really reduce your code I suggest adding the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. This will add [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) and allows you to  remove your current `CustomerDao` and simply replace it with an interface. (Code below assumes `Customer` has an id of type `Long`.).

```
public interface CustomerDao extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {}
```

Now replace the `saveCustomer` with `save` in the `CommandLineRunner`. (I added the `COmmandLineRunner` as an inner bean to be able to inject the `CustomerDao` into the method as an argument).

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringHibernateDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringHibernateDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner runner(CustomerDao dao) {
        return new CommandLineRunner() {
            @Override
            public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
                Customer customer = new Customer();
                customer.setFistName("amar");
                customer.setLastName("dev");
                customer.setEmail("amar@gmail.com");
                dao.save(customer);
            }            
        };
    }
}
```

I strongly suggest a read of the Spring Boot [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/) and learn what it is and what it does. I would also suggest learning new and accepted technologies like JPA and how Spring projects like Spring Data JPA can help you with those.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I googled a bit more and found out that hibernate version 5.2 is not yet supported with Spring 4.2. I changed the dependency to hibernate version 5.0 and created a  HibernateTransactionManager bean and it works now. Understanding Spring boot's way of configuring an ORM was not my goal, but learning this would not hurt :)

Comment: Although I am still not sure why I would want to use JPA over Hibernate. Can you please share some information about this as well ?

Comment: JPA is a standard and when using Spring Boot you get auto configuration of that. Unless you need to use some very specific hibernate feature not (yet) supported by JPA, then you might want to use plain hibernate (or just use hibernate in that corner case by getting the underlying engine). Another benefit is that you can use Spring Data JPA, which saves you from writing code for DAO's (that code you already written 100 times before). That said also use plain hibernate (`SessionFactory`) and not the `HibernateTemplate` (as also expressed in the reference guide).

Comment: Ok, got it. I guess its worthwhile to try my hands at JPA

Answer (score 0):

The root issue you have is basically the usage of `LocalSessionFactoryBean` with spring-data which already defines a `EntityManagerFactory` instance; one would probably have no reason to use it directly but `HibernateTemplate` might appear as a good reason; if you really need to use `HibernateTemplate` than create it like below such that to avoid the creation of an additional `EntityManagerFactory` instance:

```
@Bean
public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new HibernateTemplate(entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class));
}
```

PS: this solution is incomplete because I don't know how to further integrate the correctly created `HibernateTemplate` (which works with reads but not writes) with the existing transaction manager